# DataGridView Entity Framework Navigation propertiy

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview

In windows forms and DataGridView control, what is the easiest way for binding Navigation Properties like `Group.Name` in user groups model when `Users` is bound to DataGridView?

Comment: Use a ViewModel and add GroupName property to it

Comment: thanks but, model and viewmodel's mapping issue suffered me specially when records are too many in cout. Is AutoMapper safe in performance? what others generally do in this situation?

Comment: Only get and display a screenful at the time - use paging!

Comment: regarding to your [deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50675823/using-display-data-annotation-as-headertext-of-datagridview) I can share an answer if you ask a new question. Let me know if you asked a new question showing some effort to be not off-topic :)

Comment: This question is quiet old, but for future readers which came to this question, they can take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35088181/3110834).