# Show Properties of a Navigation Property in DataGridView (Second Level Properties)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview

I'm trying to display several properties from a related entity on a `DataGridView` in a [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms) app. It seems pretty ordinary to me but I'm having trouble finding examples. It's an order entry operation. OrderSheet data, the ID and the pickup date for the order, then the line items (OrderSheetItems in the model below) in the grid. The order lineitems have a navigation property, Product, based on the ProductId. I can use a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn with ProductId as ValueMember and another field as DisplayMember. But I want to include more data in other columns, size, color, material, etc.

[image: OrderSheet and OrderSheetItems with related Product]

[image: Order entry]

Here's the code for loading the data

```
try
{
    _context.OrderSheets.Include(o => o.OrderSheetItems.Select(i => i.Product)).Load();
    orderSheetBindingSource.DataSource = _context.OrderSheets.Local.ToBindingList();
}
catch (Exception ex)...
```

The ProductId is in a separate column just for experimenting, that will be the combobox later.
So is there a way to bind the other columns to the data in Product navigation property of the OrderSheetItem or do I have to handle CellValueChanged on the product id to physically set the data in the other columns? If there's a way to bind the columns then would that be via code in OnLoad or somewhere in the grid view columns designer?

TIA, Mike

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use either of these options:

1. Use `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`
2. Add corresponding properties to child entity partial class
3. Shape the query to include properties of navigation property using `Linq`
4. Use `CellFormatting` event to get value for sub property bounded columns
5. Show string representation of object by overriding `ToString()`
6. Use a custom `TypeDescriptor` to enable data binding to sub properties.

**Option 1 - Use DataGridViewComboBoxColumn**

*Usage:* This approach would be useful specially in cases which you want to keep the control editable.

In this approach you can use `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` to show any field of navigationn property. To show multiple field sub properties of navigation property in grid, use multiple `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` bound to same navigation property with different `DisplayMember`

In this approach, additional to your `ProductId` column, add more `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` to the grid and then perform these settings for all additional combo columns:

- Set `DataPropertyName` of them to `ProductId`
- Set the `DataSource` property of them, to exactly the same data source you used for main `ProductId` column, for example `productBindingSource`
- Set `ValueMember` of them to the same value member you set for product id column, it's the key column of your product table.(`ProductId`)
- Set `DisplayMember` for each of them to a column that you want to show, for example, set one of them to Name. one to Price, one to Size, ... . This way you can show related entity fields.
- Set `ReadOnly` property of them to `true`. It makes the cell read only.
- If you want to make columns readonly Set `DisplayStyle` property of them to `Nothing`. It removes dropdown style.

If you want to keep `ProductId` editable, keep the `DisplayStyle` of it to `DropDownButton`. This way when you change the value of `ProductId` column using combobox, when you leave the row and moved to next row, you will see other cells of row, shows other properties of the selected product. Also since the other combobox columns are read only and have no combobox style, the user can not change the value of them and they act only like a read only text box column that show other properties from related entity.

**Option 2 - Add corresponding properties to child entity partial class**

*Usage:* This approach would be useful when you don't need to edit values.

In this approach, You can define properties in child entity partial class return value of corresponding property of parent entity. For example for product name, define this property in order item partial class:

```
public string ProductName
{
    get
    {
        if (this.Product != null)
            return this.Product.Name;
        else 
            return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Then you can simply include products when selecting order items and bind the grid column to corresponding properties of order item.

**Option 3 - Shape the query to include properties of navigation property**

*Usage:* This approach would be useful when you don't need to edit values.

You can shape the query to include properties of navigation property. You can use an anonymous object or a View Mode simply, for example:

```
var list = db.OrderDetails.Include("Products").Where(x=>x.OrderId==1)
             .Select(x=> new OrderDetailVM() { 
                 Id = x.Id, 
                 ProductId = x.ProductId, 
                 ProductName = x.Product.Name,     
                 Price = x.Product.Price
              }).ToList();
```

**Option 4 - Use CellFormatting event to get value for sub property bounded columns**

*Usage:* This approach would be useful when you don't need to edit values.

In this approach you can use `CellFormatting` event of `DataGridView`. You can simply set `e.Value` based on column index. For example:

```
void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    //I Suppose you want to show product name in column at index 3
    if(e.RowIndex>=0 && e.ColumnIndex==3)
    {
        var orderLineItem= (OrderLineItem)(this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex]
            .DataBoundItem);
        if (order!= null && orderLineItem.Product != null)
            e.Value = orderLineItem.Product.Name);
    }
}
```

You can use different criteria to handle different columns and show different sub properties.

Also you can make it more dynamic and reusable using reflection. You can extract the value of sub property of navigation property using reflection. To do so you should create column and set `DataPropertyName` to sub properties like `Product.Name` then in `CellFormatting` event, using reflection, get the value for column. Here is a good article by Antonio Bello about this approach:

- [DataGridView: How to Bind Nested Objects](http://www.developer-corner.com/blog/2007/07/19/datagridview-how-to-bind-nested-objects/)

**Option 5 - Show string representation of object by overriding `ToString()`**

*Usage:* This approach would be useful when you don't need to edit values.

If you want to show only a single column of navigation property, you can simply override `ToString()` method of navigation property class and return suitable value. This way, when showing a property of that type in grid, you will see a friendly text. For example in partial class of `Product`, you can write:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return this.Name;
}
```

**Option 6 - Use a custom TypeDescriptor to enable data binding to sub properties**

*Usage:* This approach would be useful when you don't need to edit values.

In this approach you can create a custom TypeDescriptor that enables you to perform data binding to second-level properties.  Here is a good article by Linda Liu about this approach:

- [How to bind a DataGridView column to a second-level property of a data source](https://web.archive.org/web/20160305050810/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msdnts/archive/2007/01/19/how-to-bind-a-datagridview-column-to-a-second-level-property-of-a-data-source.aspx)

Comment: Thanks so much for all the options. I've got it about done and I was going to come back with an update but you beat me to it.
I went with option 2. I already had a partial class for MetadataType annotations and some other things so I just placed getter methods to drill down for the properties of Product (in addition to the calculated Ext = Qty * Price). In the end all I had to do was orderSheetItem.Product = product; The properties automatically appeared in the other columns via the binding source.
I'm still not going to skip that article on TypeDescriptor.
Thanks again. Mike

Comment: @JQSOFT Thanks for the feedback, I fixed the broken link to point to the post using web.archive.org, when I find time, I may add main pieces of the code to this post or another of my related post here in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

**Using CellFormatting and CellParsing to Show and Edit nested properties in DataGridView**

Features:

- Any level of nesting is supported.
- Both editable and readonly are supported

How it works:

- Each column which has "." in the `DataPropertyName` will be considered as nested property.
- `CellFormatting` event will be handled to get the value of the nested property using a recursive function.
- `CellParsing` event will be handled to set the value of the nested property using a recursive function.

Here are the methods:

```
public object GetPropertyValue(object source, string name)
{
    if (name.Contains("."))
    {
        var nameParts = name.Split(new[] { '.' }, 2);
        return GetPropertyValue(GetPropertyValue(source, nameParts[0]), nameParts[1]);
    }
    else
    {
        var property = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(source)[name];
        return property.GetValue(source);
    }
}
public void SetPropertyValue(object source, string name, object value)
{
    if (name.Contains("."))
    {
        var nameParts = name.Split(new[] { '.' }, 2);
        SetPropertyValue(GetPropertyValue(source, nameParts[0]), nameParts[1], value);
    }
    else
    {
        var property = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(source)[name];
        property.SetValue(source, value);
    }
}
```

And here are the event handlers:

```
private void CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex < 0 || e.RowIndex < 0) return;
    var dg = (DataGridView)sender;
    var propertyName = dg.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DataPropertyName;
    if (propertyName.Contains("."))
    {
        var dataObject = dg.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem;
        e.Value = GetPropertyValue(dataObject, propertyName);
    }
}

private void CellParsing(object sender, DataGridViewCellParsingEventArgs e)
{
    var dg = (DataGridView)sender;
    var propertyName = dg.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DataPropertyName;
    if (propertyName.Contains("."))
    {
        var dataObject = dg.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem;
        SetPropertyValue(dataObject, propertyName, e.Value);
    }
}
```

And here is the example:

```
var categories = new List<Category>() {
    new Category{ Id= 1, Name = "C1"},
    new Category{ Id= 2, Name = "C2"}
};
var products = new List<Product>() {
    new Product(){ Id = 1, Name ="P1", Category = categories[0]},
    new Product(){ Id = 2, Name ="P2", Category = categories[0]},
    new Product(){ Id = 3, Name ="P3", Category = categories[1]},
};
var dg = new DataGridView();
dg.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
dg.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
{
    HeaderText = "Id",
    DataPropertyName = "Id"
});
dg.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
{
    HeaderText = "Name",
    DataPropertyName = "Name"
});
dg.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
{
    HeaderText = "CategoryId",
    DataPropertyName = "Category.Id"
});
dg.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
{
    HeaderText = "CategoryName",
    DataPropertyName = "Category.Name"
});
dg.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
dg.DataSource = products;
this.Controls.Add(dg);
dg.CellFormatting += CellFormatting;
dg.CellParsing += CellParsing;
```

[image]