# How to add fields from one-to-one connected entity to a Datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview

I created a winform that contains a datagridview with all entities of one of my database-tables. I did this by creating a datasource and creating a datagridview from said datasource (according to this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj682076.aspx).

Now I have a nice datagridview and I have started customizing it. My problem is: I would like to get information from the connected entities. E.G. my table contains a list of books. Each book is connected to one author. Now I can simply overwrite the author-entities ToString-Function and have a column that specifies the author of each book. But how would I add another column that shows the DOB of the books author? I feel like, there is probably a way to edit the datasource to fit my needs but I have no idea how ...

Thanks :)

Comment: You my find this answer helpful: [Show Sub Propeties of a Navigation Propery in DataGridView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35088181/show-sub-propeties-of-a-navigation-propery-in-datagridview). The answer offers some good options to satisfy this requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is good to separate the display of your data from the way it is actually saved into a database. This way your display doesn't have to change if your database changes.

Suppose you are creating a school database with students and teachers, who are - contrary to popular belief - both Persons with name / address / telephone numbers, etc. Because relational database don't know the concept of inheritance you'll have to think of a method of where to put the inherited Person data: In a separate table? as part of the table with Teachers and as part of the table with Students? Or maybe another approach. Your choice depends on your expectations on how the data is used.

If during lifetime of your program your approach changes, you don't want to have to change all users of your data. Hence you hide how your database is organized internally.

You'll probably have organized your datagridview into rows of things that users experience as belonging together: with a book they want to see the author and his data of birth, and probably some other items. Humans are not interested that internally you have separated the author from his book.

Therefor the best way for you is to create a class that represents the user's idea of a row in your datagridview. So, an class with book, author and a date of birth properties. When the object of the class is created all items are filled from the database using the proper join and / or include statements.

Consider retrieving the data from the database only when asked for.

Comment: This was actually my initial approach: I created such a "row-class" that would include all relevant data. But I found that this approach is very slow if I want to populate the datagridview with something like 2.000 items. Especially on an older computer. Is that common or more likely caused by my (beginners) implementation?

Comment: If the total collection is very large it is quite common to populate the datagridview per " page". Only the '25' rows that are viewed at a time are downloaded. If you see a datagrid where you can't scroll, where you can only perform a page up / page down, then this method is used. Optional improvement: while the user is viewing page X, download and add pages X-1 and pages X+1. This might lead to unnecessary downloading a page. But the advantage is that for relatively small repositions the user doesn't have to wait.