# How to bind a Navigation Property (second level properties) in DataGridView using BindingSource?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview, bindingsource

I have used two entity classes for binding values into `DataGridView`. One is Estimates and Companies.

- Estimates has columns such as ***"Id, Estimate Number, Estimate Amount, CompanyId"***.
- Companies has columns such as ***"Id, Company Name, Address"***

I have created two `BindingSource` such as `EstimateBindingSource` and `CompanyBindingSource`.

1. `CompanyBindingSource` has *DataSource* as `EstimateBindingSource` and *DataMember* as `Estimates`
2. `EstimateBindingSource` has *DataSource* as `Estimates` entity Class and no *DataMember* defined.

I have bound the `EstimateBindingSource` into the `DataGridView` using grid `DataSource`.

Here, I need to show **Estimate number, Estimate Amount and Company Name** in DataGridView.. I have't able to achieve this.

**Note:** *I do not do any code behind logic to do this.. Need to achieve this only using design.*

Comment: The relation between Company and Estimate seems to be 1-N but your binding sources has been setup incorrectly.

Comment: So, Do you have any sample to achieve this kind of scenario? Please provide some example to do this..

Comment: Yes. I'll post an answer for you :)

Comment: thanks. waiting for it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Options to show Second Level Properties in DataGridView**

To show a sub property of your navigation property you can use either of these options:

1. Use a `DataGridViewComboBox` column and bind it to `CompanyId` and set it's `DataSource` to list of companies, and `DisplayMember` property to `Name` property of company and `ValueMember` to `Id` property of company.
2. Override `ToString()` method of `Company` class and return `Name` of company. Then show `Company` navigation property in grid.
3. Create a `CompanyName` property for your `Estimate` which returns its `Company.Name` value and show `CompanyName` in grid.
4. Using `CellFormatting` event of `DataGridView` and set `e.Value` to desired value (company name) you want to display in cell.
5. Shape your Estimates list using a `Linq` query or use a `ViewModel` and pass the result to data grid view.
6. Create a `TypeDescriptor` for your `Estimate` type to resolve second level properties.
   .
   To show a property of company instead of company id, you can use a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`.

**Using ComboBox Column**

Since you requested for a mechanism which uses designer without writing code I describe this option more. Here is settings you should perform:

- `EstimatesBindingSource` should bind to a list of `Estimates`
- The `DataGridView` should bind to `EstimatesBindingSource`
- `CompanyBindingSource` is only used as data source of the combo box column and should be filled using a list of `Companies`
- To show `CompanyName` in `Estimates` list, it's enough to use a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` and set it's `DataSource` to list of companies and set the `DisplayMember` to `CompanyName` and it's value member to `Id`. And bind it to `CompanyId` field of `Estimate`.

Also if your requirement is to don't show it as `ComboBox`, simply set `DisplayStyle` property of `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` to `Nothing`. It removes dropdown style.

You also may find this post helpful:

- [Show Properties of a Navigation Property in DataGridView (Second Level Properties)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35088181/show-properties-of-a-navigation-property-in-datagridview-second-level-propertie)

Comment: Is it no possible way to show the company name in datagridview text box column?

Comment: let me try with this answer you have posted

Comment: To show it in `TextBoxColumn` you should follow creating `CompanyName` property for your `Estimate` type. Or follow `TypeDescriptor` solution .Or follow `CellFormatting` event.

Comment: Also if your requirement is to don't show it as `ComboBox`, simply set `DisplayStyle` property of `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` to `Nothing`. It removes dropdown style.

Comment: Hi Reza, i have added all the above in DataGridViewComboBox column, but i need to show the company name which associated with estimate. How  may i map the estimate's company name for all the row. You have mentioned as "And bind it to CompanyId field of Estimate."

Could you please give some screenshot to clarify this?

Comment: The post is the most complete answer which you can find in this subject. It contains all you need. What problem do you faced when applying the solutions. Which solution do you used?

Comment: still i can get empty value for company column

Comment: You didn't say which option you used?

Comment: Using ComboBox Column

Comment: Also is it correct? Estimate has a CompanyId field. So each Estimate has a Company.

Comment: i have added the screen shot here. Please check

Comment: I saw your screenshot. I think you are setting up combo box incorrectly. You didn't answered my last question :) is it correct? Estimate has a CompanyId field?

Comment: I suppose Estimate has a CompanyId and a Company has and Id and a Name. So to add a combo box column, you should set the `DataSource` of the column to CompanyBindingSource, also set `DataPropertyName` to `CompanyId`, `ValueMember` to `Id`, `DisplayMameber` to `Name`.

Comment: This way, it means you want to show `CompanyId` field of `Estimate` as a `ComboBox` and when the combo box wants to show a name for the field, It shows `Name` of a company that it's `Id` is equal to `CompanyId` of the Estimate. This is the way that ComboBox works.

Comment: Then you can set the `DisplayStyle` of it to `Nothing` to don't show DropDown button and if you don't want to let the user change the value, set `ReadOnly` of column to `true`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks Reza. It's working as i expected.. Thanks for giving valuable response from your side.

Comment: I removed the picture, we don't need the picture anymore.