# Loading related entity's property into DatagridView (Databinding with Winforms and EF 6 Code First)

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview

I have two POCO EF classes:

```
public class Message
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public String Text { get; set; }
    public bool IsPrivate { get; set; }

    UPDATE2: public Giud UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    UPDATE2: public Giud UserRoleId { get; set; }

    public virtual UserRole UserRole { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }
}

public class UserRole
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Accoridng to [Entity Framework Databinding with WinForms MSDN tutrotial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj682076(v=vs.113).aspx):
**UPDATE:**

1. I create a DataSource for my Message class. All related entitie's properties are present in it:
   [image]
2. Then I drag-n-drop it on my DataGridView and VS generates columns for all Message's properties.
3. But I want to have a column for related entity's property (for example **Message.User.Age** or even **Message.User.UserRole.Name**). When I try add a new column I have no option for that:
   [image]

Is there a "out-of-the-box" way to display related entity's property into my DataGridView?
Or the only way is to create custom DTO object projected from EF entity's properties that I need?

**UPDATE2:** I've read [Show Properties of a Navigation Property in DataGridView (Second Level Properties)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35088181/show-properties-of-a-navigation-property-in-datagridview-second-level-propertie) question as **Reza Aghaei** suggested. And tried to implement **Option 1 - Use DataGridViewComboBoxColumn**, but failed. That is what I've done:

1. Added UserId field to Messages class - see class description above.
2. I create a DataSource for my Message class (Data Sources->Add new data Source->Object->Selected Message class):
   [image]
   Looks like related entitie's properties are present in it:
   [image]
3. Then I drag-n-drop it on my DataGridView and VS generates columns for all Message's properties.
4. After that I followed **Option 1 - Use DataGridViewComboBoxColumn** guideline and converted column for UserId to DataGridViewComboBoxColumn. But I got stuck on the:

> Set ValueMember of them to the same value member you set for product
> id column, it's the key column of your product table.(ProductId)
>
> Set DisplayMember for each of them to a column that you want to show, for
> example, set one of them to Name. one to Price, one to Size, ... .
> This way you can show related entity fields.

I don't see any User properties except for UserId:
[image]

What is my mistake?

Comment: try this: var _messages = db.Messages.ToList(); this.messageBindingSource.DataSource = _messages;

Comment: There are couple of options. Take a look at this post: [Show Properties of a Navigation Property in DataGridView (Second Level Properties)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35088181/3110834)

Comment: You should `include` the tables that you want to load or you should enable `lazyloading`.

Comment: @Berkay How can it help me if I have no option to add a column that is databound to  related entity's property (see my updated question)?

Comment: @RezaAghaei I've tried to follow **Option 1 - Use DataGridViewComboBoxColumn** guideline - but failed. See **UPDATE2**. Any suggestion?

Comment: @bairog It seems you didn't followed the steps correctly. If you are going to use Option 1, you need to load a list of users and use it as data source of combobox column, this way, when choosing ValueMember and DisplayMember you will see User properties rather than Message properties.

Comment: Option 1 is useful when you want to keep the list editable. But if you just want to show data and you are not going to make it ediable, go with option 2,3,4 or 6. They are really easy to implement. For example take a look at option 6, it's just an overrid of ToString method. Just make sure that you include user when loading data. `db.Messages.Include(x=>User)` also add (`using system.Data.Entity;`).

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thx, now it works.

Comment: I closed your 2 recent questions just because I was sure that the linked answers are complete and can solve your problem. In cases that you have any doubt about linked answers after reading them. feel free to ask question about them.

Answer (score 0):

try first loading the data from the db, then binding it to the control

var _messages = db.Messages.ToList(); 
this.messageBindingSource.DataSource = _messages;

Comment: How can it help me if I have no option to add a column that is databound to  related entity's property (see my updated question)?