# Class with hierarchy to DataGridview

Tags: c#, class, datagridview

I have the following class, which has Fixture as the parent class -> FixtureSensors etc are child classes:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FixtureData
{
    class Fixture
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public List<FixtureSensors> Sensors = new List<FixtureSensors>();
        public List<FixturePneumaticValves> Valves { get; set; }
    }

    class FixturePneumaticValves
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Hardware { get; set; }
        public string Connection { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public List<FixturePneumaticUnits> Units { get; set; }
    }
    class FixtureSensors
    {
        public string Fixture { get; set; }
        public string Hardware { get; set; }
        public string Connection { get; set; }
        public string Unit { get; set; }
    }

    class FixturePneumaticUnits
    {
        public string Fixture { get; set; }
        public string Hardware { get; set; }
        public string Connection { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I would like to display information from the different classes on a datagridview which is editable. I managed to display this information, however to make the datagridview editable I had to include a class after the linq select new statement:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using FixtureData;

namespace GridViewObjects_DB
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private BindingSource source = new BindingSource();    
        static List<Fixture> Fixtures = new List<Fixture>()
         {
            new Fixture() { Id = 0, Name = "S7K010LFX1", Type = "GEO WELDING",Sensors = new List<FixtureSensors>()
            {
              new FixtureSensors(){Connection = "0.0", Hardware = "S7K010LFX1VS1",Unit = "102L-C1"},
              new FixtureSensors(){Connection = "0.1", Hardware = "S7K010LFX1VS1",Unit = "103L-C1"},
              new FixtureSensors(){Connection = "0.2", Hardware = "S7K010LFX1VS1",Unit = "103L-C1"},
              new FixtureSensors(){Connection = "0.3", Hardware = "S7K010LFX1VS1",Unit = "104L-C1"},
              new FixtureSensors(){Connection = "0.4", Hardware = "S7K010LFX1VS1",Unit = "105L-C1"}
            },Valves = new List<FixturePneumaticValves>()
            {
                new FixturePneumaticValves(){Id=0,Connection = "0.0",Hardware = "S7K010LFX1VS1",Type = "Clp",Units = new List<FixturePneumaticUnits>()
                {
                    new FixturePneumaticUnits(){Hardware = "S7K010LFX1VS1",Connection = "0.6"},
                    new FixturePneumaticUnits(){Hardware = "S7K010LFX1VS1",Connection = "1.0"},
                    new FixturePneumaticUnits(){Hardware = "S7K010LFX1VS1",Connection = "1.2"},
                    new FixturePneumaticUnits(){Hardware = "S7K010LFX1VS1",Connection = "1.4"},
                    new FixturePneumaticUnits(){Hardware = "S7K010LFX1VS1",Connection = "1.6"}
                }
             }
            }
            }
        };

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           source.DataSource =(from fixture in Fixtures
                               from sensors in fixture.Sensors
                               select new Fixture() {Name = sensors.Fixture}
                        );
           dataGridView1.DataSource = source;
           dataGridView1.ReadOnly = false;
           dataGridView1.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

This limits me to only display properties of the Fixture class and I would like to know of a way around this.

Comment: Etiher you Select the properties you need so you have a nice flat design. Or you add accessor to the father class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show Properties of a Navigation Property in DataGridView (Second Level Properties)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35088181/show-properties-of-a-navigation-property-in-datagridview-second-level-propertie)