# Data Grid View Combo Box Not Working Properly Using Entity framework

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview, combobox

I am developing a small desktop application using win forms with entity framework code first approach,

I need to display Items table in a Datagrid View and it has a column called "Category" and which is a foreign key from another table called Categories, I used DataGridViewComboBoxColumn to bind the data source,

[image: DataGridViewComboBoxColumn]

But when I load the form it is displaying as shown below

[image: Data Grid View of Items Table]

The Full Text in Category Column is "SimpleBilling.Model.Category"

Here is my models below

Items Model

```
    public class Item
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string  Code { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public string Unit { get; set; }
        public string Barcode { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Categories { get; set; }
    }
```

Category Model

```
    public class Category
    {
        [Key]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(150)]
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
    }
```

But When Click on the Combo box then data is loading into that Combobox properly

Following is my source code to load data object into Datasource on form_load Event

```
 using (BillingContext db = new BillingContext())
 {
    itemBindingSource.DataSource = db.Items.ToList();
    categoryBindingSource.DataSource = db.Categories.ToList();                   
 }
```

Is there any suggestions to fix this issue please?.... thank you

Comment: Images not displayed properly please someone suggests an edit to display them properly

Comment: Set the `DataPropertyName` as `CategoryId` if you have in your model.

Comment: Take a look at option 1 in this post: [Show Properties of a Navigation Property in DataGridView (Second Level Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35117378/3110834)

Comment: Category is an object in my model and cannot see Category Id in "DataPropertyName"

Comment: My suggestion is including foreign key columns in the model, when you create the model and using them for these kind of scenarios.

Comment: I think  it is already there, I am using Code first approach, can you see the models I have added in the question later, and please let me know if there is any problem in it, I checked in the SQL server as well and relation is there