# Why is my implementation of a custom TypeDescriptor to retrieve second-level property for DataGridView not working?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to implement Linda Liu's [solution](https://web.archive.org/web/20160305050810/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msdnts/archive/2007/01/19/how-to-bind-a-datagridview-column-to-a-second-level-property-of-a-data-source.aspx) for displaying second-level properties in a DataGridView.  If I'm understanding everything correctly, when a DataSource is set, C# uses a method called ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetProperties, which "grabs" PropertyDescriptors from the class module and adds them to a collection.  So Liu's solution is to create PropertyDescriptors for the second level properties and to return them along with the original PropertyDescriptors.

In my case, EmployeeModel has a property JobTitle.  JobTitle has properties Name and ID.  My SQL joins these and returns a list of EmployeeModel with JobTitle.Name and JobTitle.ID set.  I want to display JobTitle.Name as a column in EmployeeGridView.  (When I've managed to make this work, I'll do the same for several other properties of EmployeeModel.)

Everything compiles, but at runtime the effect is not achieved.  I end up with an extra column with no visible content, while the original JobTitle column is replicated as the rightmost column.

[Screenshot of my application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmK6T.png)

```
namespace WorkDesk_Library.Binding_Assist
{
    class MyTypeDescriptionProvider : TypeDescriptionProvider
    {
        private ICustomTypeDescriptor td;

        public MyTypeDescriptionProvider()
           : this(TypeDescriptor.GetProvider(typeof(EmployeeModel)))

        {
        }

        public MyTypeDescriptionProvider(TypeDescriptionProvider parent)
            : base(parent)
        {
        }

        public override ICustomTypeDescriptor GetTypeDescriptor(Type objectType, object instance)
        {
            if (td == null)
            {
                td = base.GetTypeDescriptor(objectType, instance);
                td = new MyCustomTypeDescriptor(td);
            }
            return td;
        }
    }
}
```

```
namespace WorkDesk_Library.Binding_Assist
{
    class MyCustomTypeDescriptor : CustomTypeDescriptor
    {

        public MyCustomTypeDescriptor(ICustomTypeDescriptor parent)
            : base(parent)
        {
        }

        public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties()
        {
            PropertyDescriptorCollection cols = base.GetProperties();

            PropertyDescriptor JobTitle = cols["JobTitle"];

            PropertyDescriptorCollection JobTitle_child = JobTitle.GetChildProperties();

            PropertyDescriptor[] array = new PropertyDescriptor[cols.Count + 2];

            cols.CopyTo(array, 0);

            array[cols.Count] = new SubPropertyDescriptor(JobTitle, JobTitle_child["Name"], "JobTitle_Name");

            array[cols.Count + 1] = new SubPropertyDescriptor(JobTitle, JobTitle_child["ID"], "JobTitle_ID");

            PropertyDescriptorCollection newcols = new PropertyDescriptorCollection(array);

            return newcols;
        }

    }
}
```

```
namespace WorkDesk_Library.Interfaces
{
    class SubPropertyDescriptor : PropertyDescriptor
    {


        private PropertyDescriptor _subPD;
        private PropertyDescriptor _parentPD;

        public SubPropertyDescriptor(PropertyDescriptor parentPD, PropertyDescriptor subPD, string pdname)
            : base(pdname, null)
        {
            _subPD = subPD;
            _parentPD = parentPD;
        }

        public override Type ComponentType
        {
            get { return _parentPD.ComponentType; }
        }

        public override bool IsReadOnly { get { return false; } }

        public override Type PropertyType
        {
            get { return _subPD.PropertyType; }
        }

        public override bool CanResetValue(object component)
        {
            return false;
        }

        public override object GetValue(object component)
        {
            return _subPD.GetValue(_parentPD.GetValue(component));
        }

        public override void ResetValue(object component)
        {
        }

        public override void SetValue(object component, object value)
        {
            _subPD.SetValue(_parentPD.GetValue(component), value);
            OnValueChanged(component, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

```
 public void CreateEmployeeTable()
        {
            EmployeeGridView.DataSource = globalEmployeeList;
            EmployeeGridView.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Employee ID";
            EmployeeGridView.Columns["ID"].DisplayIndex = 0;
            EmployeeGridView.Columns["ListView"].DisplayIndex = 1;
            EmployeeGridView.Columns["ListView"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
            EmployeeGridView.Columns["Department"].DisplayIndex = 2;
            EmployeeGridView.Columns["JobTitle"].DisplayIndex = 3;
            EmployeeGridView.Columns["JobTitle"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
            EmployeeGridView.Columns["Nickname"].Visible = false;
            EmployeeGridView.Columns["FirstName"].Visible = false;
            EmployeeGridView.Columns["LastName"].Visible = false;
            EmployeeGridView.Columns["HireDate"].Visible = false;
        }
```

Comment: There are other solutions as well to [Show Properties of a Navigation Property in DataGridView (Second Level Properties)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35117378/3110834)

Comment: Indeed, Reza.  And I'm tempted to go through them all.  But I thought I'd be best served sticking with one solution for as long as possible and trying to understand its logic before trying something else.

Comment: I've listed this option as the last option ;)

Comment: Oh jeez, I just realized that Answer was yours!  It was a really excellent post, and I appreciate the effort.  I'm assuming you're saying you listed the Liu solution last because of the level of complexity, in which case I'll pull out less of my hair implementing one of the other choices?  In any case, for the moment I've decided to redesign the ui with listboxes.  I don't believe my ego can handle any more crushing defeat.

Comment: Comparing to all other options it's more complex. And I hope you are not thinking of putting a few listbox side by side to play role of a grid.

Comment: Absolutely not.  My initial idea was to display certain properties in an employee table like it currently appears in Excel and others in listboxes, such as Email addresses and accomodations.  But it wouldn't be absolutely awful to integrate more listboxes with single items listed, like Job Title.  I'm not giving up on the DataGridView yet, though.  I'm working on the combobox thing, and i think I'm getting somewhere.