# Using ComboBox to show second-level properties in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

As I understand it, ComboBox columns are more dynamic for binding in DataGridView than standard columns, and this flexibility can be used to use DisplayMembers from second-order properties.  This approach is the first mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35088181/show-properties-of-a-navigation-property-in-datagridview-second-level-propertie/35117378#35117378) by [Mr. Aghaei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3110834/reza-aghaei).

However, I'm not getting it right.  My application still throws the exception that "Name" doesn't exist.

```
 public void CreateEmployeeTable()
        {

            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn jobTitleColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
            jobTitleColumn.HeaderText = "Job Title";
            jobTitleColumn.DataPropertyName = "JobTitle";
            jobTitleColumn.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.Nothing;
            jobTitleColumn.DataPropertyName = "ID";
            jobTitleColumn.DataSource = globalEmployeeList;
            jobTitleColumn.ValueMember = "ID";
            jobTitleColumn.DisplayMember = "Name";
            jobTitleColumn.ReadOnly = true;

            employeeGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            employeeGridView.ColumnCount = 2;
            employeeGridView.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Employee ID";
            employeeGridView.Columns[0].DisplayIndex = 0;
            employeeGridView.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "ID";
            employeeGridView.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Name";
            employeeGridView.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "ListView";
            employeeGridView.Columns[1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
            employeeGridView.Columns.Add(jobTitleColumn);
            
            employeeGridView.DataSource = globalEmployeeList;                                                                               
        }
```

Here is the class definition:

```
     
    public class EmployeeModel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string Nickname { get; set; }
        public DepartmentModel Department { get; set; }
        public TitleModel JobTitle { get; set; }
        public DateTime HireDate { get; set; }
        public List<EmailModel> EmailList { get; set; } = new List<EmailModel>();
        public List<PhoneModel> PhoneList { get; set; } = new List<PhoneModel>();
        public List<RestrictionModel> RestrictionsList { get; set; } = new List<RestrictionModel>();
        public List<CitationModel> CitationsList { get; set; } = new List<CitationModel>();
        public List<CertificationModel> CertificationList { get; set; } = new List<CertificationModel>();

        public string ListView
        {
            get
            {
                return $"{LastName}, {FirstName}";
            }
        }

        public string ToEmailString()
        {
            IEnumerable<string> employeeEmailStrings = EmailList.Select(emmod => emmod.ToString());
            string employeeEmailString = string.Join($"{Environment.NewLine}", employeeEmailStrings);

            IEnumerable<string> certificationStrings = CertificationList.Select(clistmod => clistmod.ToString());
            string certificationString = string.Join($"{Environment.NewLine}", certificationStrings);

            IEnumerable<string> phoneStrings = PhoneList.Select(plistmod => plistmod.ToString());
            string phoneString = string.Join($"{Environment.NewLine}", phoneStrings);

            return $"{FirstName}, {LastName}: {Environment.NewLine} -{JobTitle.Name}- {Environment.NewLine} {employeeEmailString} {Environment.NewLine} {certificationString} {Environment.NewLine} {phoneString}";
        }



        public class EmailModel
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string Address { get; set; }
            public string Type { get; set; }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return $"{Address} ({Type})";
            }
        }

        public class PhoneModel
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string Number { get; set; }
            public string Type { get; set; }
            public override string ToString()
            {
                return $"{Number} ({Type})";
            }

        }
    }
```

And the definition for TitleModel:

```
    public class TitleModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int ID { get; set; }  

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To support the post [Show Properties of a Navigation Property in DataGridView (Second Level Properties)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35117378/3110834) I've already shared a few example in the same post or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65691586/3110834) which allows showing second level properties and allow editing them.

Here I will share a few more examples, each example has been written as a minimal complete verifiable example, you can just copy and paste in an empty form and they will work.

These are the examples:

- Using ToString()
- Using CellFormatting
- Using ComboBox Column for Navigation Object
- Using ComboBox Column for Foreign key column

#### Example - Using ToString()

*When:* You don't want to change `JobTitle` of Employee

*How:* By overriding `ToString` method of `JobTitle`

```
class JobTitle
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public JobTitle JobTitle { get; set; }
}
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    var jobTitles = new List<JobTitle>() {
        new JobTitle {Id= 1, Name="Manager" },
        new JobTitle {Id= 2, Name="Employee" },
    };
    var employees = new List<Employee>() {
        new Employee{ Id = 1, Name ="John", JobTitle = jobTitles[0] },
        new Employee{ Id = 2, Name ="Jane", JobTitle = jobTitles[1] },
        new Employee{ Id = 3, Name ="Jack", JobTitle = jobTitles[1] },
    };
    var dg = new DataGridView();
    dg.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    dg.DataSource = employees;
    this.Controls.Add(dg);
}
```

#### Example - Using CellFormatting

*When:* You don't want to change `JobTitle` of Employee

*How:* By handling `CellFormatting` event of `DataGridView` and setting `Value` of the event args to a string representation of `JobTitle`

```
class JobTitle
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public JobTitle JobTitle { get; set; }
}
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    var jobTitles = new List<JobTitle>() {
        new JobTitle {Id= 1, Name="Manager" },
        new JobTitle {Id= 2, Name="Employee" },
    };
    var employees = new List<Employee>() {
        new Employee{ Id = 1, Name ="John", JobTitle = jobTitles[0] },
        new Employee{ Id = 2, Name ="Jane", JobTitle = jobTitles[1] },
        new Employee{ Id = 3, Name ="Jack", JobTitle = jobTitles[1] },
    };
    var dg = new DataGridView();
    dg.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    dg.DataSource = employees;
    dg.CellFormatting += (obj, args) =>
    {
        if (args.RowIndex >= 0 &&
            dg.Columns[args.ColumnIndex].DataPropertyName == "JobTitle")
            args.Value = ((Employee)dg.Rows[args.RowIndex].DataBoundItem).JobTitle.Name;
    };
    this.Controls.Add(dg);
}
```

#### Example - Using ComboBox Column for Foreign key column

*When:* You want to be able to change the `JobTitle` of `Employee` and you have the foreign key column in your model.

*How:* Using a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` for that property, having a data source containing all job titles, and setting `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` to proper properties.

```
class JobTitle
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int JobTitleId { get; set; }
}
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    var jobTitles = new List<JobTitle>() {
        new JobTitle {Id= 1, Name="Manager" },
        new JobTitle {Id= 2, Name="Employee" },
    };
    var employees = new List<Employee>() {
        new Employee{ Id = 1, Name ="John", JobTitleId = 1 },
        new Employee{ Id = 2, Name ="Jane", JobTitleId = 2 },
        new Employee{ Id = 2, Name ="Jack", JobTitleId = 2 },
    };
    var dg = new DataGridView();
    dg.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    dg.DataSource = employees;
    dg.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() 
    { 
        DataPropertyName = "Id", HeaderText = "Id" 
    });
    dg.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() 
    {
        DataPropertyName = "Name", HeaderText = "Name" 
    });
    dg.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()
    {
        DataPropertyName = "JobTitleId",
        HeaderText = "JobTitleId",
        DataSource = jobTitles,
        ValueMember = "Id",
        DisplayMember = "Name",
    });
    this.Controls.Add(dg);
}
```

#### Example - Using ComboBox Column for Navigation Object

*When:* You want to be able to change the `JobTitle` of `Employee` and you don't have the foreign key column in your model, instead you want to use the navigation object in your model.

*How:* Using a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` for that property, having a data source containing all job titles, without setting `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` to proper properties. Then handling `CellFormatting` to set the display value of the cell and handling `CellParsing` to get value from `ComboBox` and put into the cell.

```
class JobTitle
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public JobTitle JobTitle { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    var jobTitles = new List<JobTitle>() {
        new JobTitle {Id= 1, Name="Manager" },
        new JobTitle {Id= 1, Name="Employee" },
    };
    var employees = new List<Employee>() {
        new Employee{ Id = 1, Name ="John", JobTitle = jobTitles[0] },
        new Employee{ Id = 2, Name ="Jane", JobTitle = jobTitles[1] },
        new Employee{ Id = 2, Name ="Jack", JobTitle = jobTitles[1] },
    };
    var dg = new DataGridView();
    dg.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    dg.DataSource = employees;
    dg.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() 
    { 
        DataPropertyName = "Id", HeaderText = "Id" 
    });
    dg.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() 
    {
        DataPropertyName = "Name", HeaderText = "Name" 
    });
    dg.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()
    {
        DataPropertyName = "JobTitle",
        HeaderText = "JobTitle",
        DataSource = jobTitles,
    });
    dg.CellFormatting += (obj, args) =>
    {
        if (args.RowIndex >= 0 &&
            dg.Columns[args.ColumnIndex].DataPropertyName == "JobTitle")
        {
            args.Value = 
        ((Employee)dg.Rows[args.RowIndex].DataBoundItem).JobTitle.ToString();
        }
    };
    dg.CellParsing += (obj, args) =>
    {
        if (args.RowIndex >= 0 &&
            dg.Columns[args.ColumnIndex].DataPropertyName == "JobTitle")
        {
            args.Value = ((ComboBox)dg.EditingControl).SelectedItem;
            args.ParsingApplied = true;
        }
    };
    this.Controls.Add(dg);
}
```

Comment: That's really great.  I realize now the solution for working with navigation properties wasn't intended to work with foreign keys.  Also, one of the problems I've had has been assigning class objects as properties, whereas your method sets the foreign key as the property, and C# is able to map this relationship as sql would.  Is this correct?  Is it correct to assume I should stop assigning classes as properties of another class and instead use the foreign key, or is there a time for both?

Comment: Including foreign keys in model is a choice. You can choose to include foreign keys (as well as navigation properties) or you can choose just to keep navigation properties. I personally prefer to keep foreign key columns in the model; it makes UI scenarios like data binding and editing easier. In above example, I've covered both scenarios (with/without foreign key) in the last two examples here.

Comment: Thank you for your help and your patience.  I've only been in C# for about a month, and I'm still learning its syntax and libraries.  I've learned a lot about the language from looking over your code, beyond the scope of my op, e.g. using the base keyword.  I'm especially intrigued by the `dg.CellParsing += (obj, args) =>` construction and will be reading up on that syntax.

Comment: No worries @JoshuaWhite. `myControl.Click += (obj, args) => {/*something*/}` is basically telling handle `Click` of `myControl` using the specified lambda event handler. It's similar to `myControl.Click += myControl_Click`  and later have the function `void myControl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {/*something*/}`

Comment: By the way, I noticed that you have not accepted or upvoted the answers you have received to your questions. I didn't review the answers, but just in case you are not familiar with Accept and Upvote, take a look at [tour]. It's not compulsory at all, but it's recommended as it make the posts more useful for future readers and also give some reputation scores to the authors.

Comment: I've made some progress, but I'm still not able to get the table to display properly--or at all, actually.  When I step through the code, everything is populated, but the table doesn't appear at runtime.  That's the purpose of  `this.Controls.Add(dg);`,  yes?

Should I update my post with my current code?

Comment: `this.Controls.Add(dg);` will add the `DataGridView` to the Form.

Comment: The reason that I created the DataGridView in the code is just because of the example purpose to make the example standalone without any dependency to Designer to allow you to give it a try by copy and paste. While it's OK if you even copy and paste it and use it as is, but usually I don't expect you do that for a real project, You probably use designer and drop a DataGridView and you want to fill that DataGridView, and you don't want to create a new one and just add it to the form.

Comment: Of course.  I had created the DataGridView with Designer, so that line was redundant in my case.  I'm getting closer.  Still throwing an unhandled exception at runtime, though.  But I think I know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Yep, I figured out what I was doing wrong, and it all works perfectly now!  Incidentally, is there a way to hide the dropdown arrow?  Edit: Never mind.  I saw in your original post: DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.Nothing

Comment: Set [DisplayStyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.displaystyle?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) property of the column to [`DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.Nothing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxdisplaystyle?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

Comment: I have everything working, but could you explain the use of 
`protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);`

It works without using an override here, correct?  You have it written this way so that I could, if I wanted to, copy and paste your code directly into my project?  Or is there something going on here that I'm not understanding?

Comment: Just for ease of copy paste. You usually handle `Load` event of the form instead.

Comment: Just for your information, `OnLoad` is the method which will be called during load of the form and it is responsible for raising `Load` event. That's why you see I kept `base.OnLoad(e);` because it calls the base implementation of `OnLoad` which raises the `Load` event.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought.  Just double-checking that I wasn't doing harm by writing the table into the regular OnLoad event.  Thanks.