# Problem with Entity Framework 6 and WinForm Datagrid

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid, entity-framework-6

I have a problem with my datagrid, it shows all the info from the book table but I cannot see the includes info from authors and genre tables in the columns like in this screenshot:

[image]

This is my code:

```
var DbBooks = db.Books
                .Include(b => b.Author)
                .Include(b => b.Genre)
                .ToList();
datagrindBooks.DataSource = DbBooks;
```

Comment: [DataGridView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/datagridview-control-overview-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) is different from [DataGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagrid?view=netframework-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

Comment: That's because those columns are showing an Author and a Genre object; the `string` representation of those objects. So you can override the `ToString()` in those classes and for example return the author full name or the genre name. To see other possible solutions, you can take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35088181/show-properties-of-a-navigation-property-in-datagridview-second-level-propertie) or the [other one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35117378/3110834) to see how to show navigation properties in `DataGridView`.

Answer (score 1):

You could put some NotMapped properties into the Books entity

```
public partial class Book{

  [NotMapped] //so EF ignores it
  public string AuthorName { get => Author.Name; }
  ...
}
```

and so on; they don't store data themselves, they just proxy from the sub objects and DataGridView will find them and display the values they return. If you want it two way you'll need a set too

Comment: thx , i have one more problem i want to hide some propeties i getting in my list , i used the atrribute Browsable(false) is it ok or it will do me harm in future in my code using ef?

Comment: I'd just remove the columns from the datagridview after it has autogenerated them tbh.. `dgvWhatever.AutoGenerateCOlumns = true; dgvWhatever.DataSource = booksList; dgvWhatever.Columns.Remove("BookCopys");` .. they're generated when the datasource is set.. but I do believe that browsable(false) works to make DGV ignore the property