# How to use LINQ Query Syntax to populate a GridView in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

**I am trying to populate a GridView in Windows Forms using Entity Framework. I have the following classes with this data.**

```
    Class Office
        OfficeId
        Region
        Address
        City

        [ForeignKey("OfficeContactId")]
        public virtual OfficeContact OfficeContacts

        [ForeignKey("RegionalTechnicianId")]
        public virtual RegionalTechnician RegionalTechnicians
    
Class OfficeContact
        OfficeContactId
        Name
        Email
        Phone
    
Class RegionalTechnician
        RegionalTechnicianId
        Name
        Email
        Phone
```

**The following works fine to populate the GridView with the Office data (OfficeId, Region, Address, City) but I am not sure how to pull in the other data.**

```
dataGridView.DataSource = context.Offices.ToList<Office>();
```

Comment: [Loading Related Entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

Comment: [Show navigation property in DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35088181/3110834)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dataGridView.DataSource = (from office in context.Offices      
                          join OfficeContact in context.OfficeContacts on office.OfficeId equals OfficeContact.OfficeContactId 
                          join RegionalTechnician in context.RegionalTechnicians on office.OfficeId equals RegionalTechnician.RegionalTechnicianId
                          select new
                          {
                            OfficeId = office.OfficeId,
                            Region = office.Region,
                            Address = office.Address,
                            City = office.City,
                            OfficeContactId = OfficeContact.OfficeContactId,
                            OfficeContactName = OfficeContact.Name,
                            OfficeContactEmail = OfficeContact.Email,
                            OfficeContactPhone = OfficeContact.Phone,
                            RegionalTechnicianId = RegionalTechnician.RegionalTechnicianId,
                            RegionalTechnicianName = RegionalTechnician.Name,
                            RegionalTechnicianEmail = RegionalTechnician.Email,
                            RegionalTechnicianPhone = RegionalTechnician.Phone                
                          }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

tow solution

1. using LINQ.

   please visit this page.

   [show-properties-of-a-navigation-property-in-datagridview-second-level-propertie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35088181/show-properties-of-a-navigation-property-in-datagridview-second-level-propertie)
2. Create view in database and view model in Code.

For Example :

```
Create View officeView
as 
Select o.OfficeId,
       o.Region,
       o.Address,
       o.City,
       r.Email,
       r.Name,
       r.Phone
From Office o
    left join RegionalTechnician r on r.RegionalTechnicianId= o.RegionalTechnicianId
    left join OfficeContact oc on oc.OfficeContactId= o.OfficeContactId
```

In code: Update Context(Entity Framework)

After Update Context, you have model like this

```
public partial class officeView
{
    public long OfficeId { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

Then:

```
dataGridView.DataSource = context.officeViews.ToList();
```

Comment: PascalCase for classes, please