# Customize DataGridView filled by linq-query

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datagridview

I have 2 SQL-Tables, which I created via SQL Server Managment Studio (including PK & FK):

[sql-tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WO3wo.png)

In my WinForm Project in Visual Studio, I added the data-model via *Code First to an Existing Database* and read the data via the following linq-query:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = dbContext.deliveries.OrderBy(d => d.id).ToList();
```

Now the datagridView1 consists of the columns from the table "deliveries", but instead of showing a column *customer_id* I would like show the corresponding name and adress of the customer.

Some other answers on stackoverflow suggest to edit the query and use the "include" property. So I tried to use

```
deliveries.Include(d=>d.customer.name).OrderBy(d => d.id).ToList();
```

but this throws an Exception while running with the folowing Error:

`The EntityType '*.customer' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'name'`

which I dont understand, since my Classes follow the form of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/relationships AND are created via *Code First from existing database*.

```
      public partial class deliveries
    {
        public int id { get; set; }

        public int? amount { get; set; }
        
        public int? customer_id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("customer_id")]
        public virtual customer customer { get; set; }

    }
```

```
   public partial class customer
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public customer()
        {
            deliveries = new HashSet<deliveries>();
        }
        [Key]
        public int customerID { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [StringLength(10)]
        public string address { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<deliveries> deliveries { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Add your classes `Deleivery`, `Customer`. Show your mapping.

Comment: Added the classes above. Not sure what you mean with mapping?

Comment: I've shared a few solutions in this post: [Show Properties of a Navigation Property in DataGridView (Second Level Properties)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35088181/3110834), including: using DataGridViewComboBoxColumn, adding properties to the entities, shaping the result of the Linq query, using CellFormatting, overriding ToString of entities, using a custom TypeDescriptor. It also have an example and usage scenario for each case.

Comment: @RezaAghaei is nested displaymemberpath supported?

Comment: @RezaAghaei thanks, your link is a good read. But all i needed was the "select" command as mentioned in the accepted answer below.

Comment: @Danietm and it's the **Option 3 - Shape the query to include properties of navigation property** in the linked answer 

Comment: @LeiYang Look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65691586/3110834), 0 upvotes  but working.

Comment: @RezaAghaei of course ;)
can anybody help me with question in the comment of the accepted answer below please?

Comment: @Danietm It will of course not be `List<Delivery>`. It will be `List<anonymous type>`. What's your requirement exactly and why you would like to keep it as `List<Delivery>`?

Comment: @RezaAghaei The point is not to make it List<anonymous type>. It can be any type, but the point is that i would like to put it in a seperate method and return the values of the query. Since returning an <anonymous type> is not recommended at all

Comment: You have two options, 1- Define a class containing the properties that you need and in the select statement, instead of instantiating a new anonymous type, instantiate and initialize that class. 2- Just return List<X> from the general purpose method, then later based on the requirement in different places shape the list using a select statement.

Comment: I still advise you to read the linked post and consider option 1, 4 or 5 in the linked post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show only specific values, you have to do custom projection and specify shape of your result via `Select`. It can be DTO or anonymous class, and no Includes are needed.

```cs
var result = deliveries
    .OrderBy(d => d.id)
    .Select(d => new 
    {
        d.customer.name,
        d.customer.address
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! How can I use it in a seperate method, since the returned list is not of shape `List<deliveries>` anymore?